# Firefox service worker (as proxy) seems to work, but JS modules never run

Tags: javascript, firefox, service-worker

I'm playing around with service workers. The following code should proxy JS files to patch the imports so that they conform to platform standards (i.e., `"./"`, `"../"`, `"/"`, or `"http://..."`).

Works great in Chromium (67.0.3396.79 on Arch Linux). And seems to work just as well in Firefox (60.0.2 (64-bit) on Arch), at least from the network tab, I can see all of the patched sources loading, but for some reason the JS modules aren't running. Can't `console.log` etc. or anything. Not sure how to get Firefox to bootstrap the application.

I noticed that the fetch headers are all `toLowerCase`ed, but I read up on that [here](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/pull/476) and Mozilla also points out that header names are case-insensitive [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

I also thought maybe because the content-length was possibly changed that the file wasn't being received completely, but I didn't see any parse errors and indeed the network tab had the correct content-length changes, so I ruled that out.

```
const maybeAppendJS = (x) =>
    x.endsWith(".js")
        ? x
        : `${x}.js`;


const maybePatchURL = (x) =>
    x.match(/(^'@.*'(.)?$)|(^"@.*"(.)?$)/)
        ? `"/node_modules/${maybeAppendJS(eval(x))}";`
        : x;


const maybePatchImport = (x) =>
    x.startsWith("import ")
        ? x.split(/\s/).map(maybePatchURL).join(" ")
        : x;


async function maybeRewriteImportStatements(event) {

    let candidate = event.request.url;
    const url = maybeAppendJS(candidate);

    const resp = await fetch(url);

    if (!resp.headers.get("content-type").startsWith("text")) {
        const text = await resp.text();
        const newText = text.split(/\n/g)
            .map(maybePatchImport)
            .join("\n");

        return new Response(newText, {headers: resp.headers});
    }

    if (resp.headers.get("content-type").startsWith("text/")) {
        const location = `${url.substring(0, url.length - 3)}/index.js`;
        return new Response(null, {status: 302, headers: {location: location}});
    }

    console.log("Service worker should never get here");

}

this.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    if (event.request.destination === "script" || event.request.referrer.endsWith(".js") || event.request.url.endsWith(".js")) {
        event.respondWith(maybeRewriteImportStatements(event));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by upgrading to the Firefox nightly (62.0a1.20180611-1).